# DOM Element Active State Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve an effect when I click on a DOM element, in this case a `list`, the target `list` would rotate and stay that way.

It's kind of hard to explain so here's the [link](http://www.mattlebrun.com/hacks/b-circ-menu/) to what I am currently working on.

When you long press on the rounded gray object a list of menu would slowly reveal. However, once you let go it'll disappear again.

The behavior I'm aiming is that clicking just once on the rounded gray object would reveal the menu and that the menu stays revealed.

It's quite long so I'll just give you the [css link](http://www.mattlebrun.com/hacks/b-circ-menu/assets/css/circ-menu2.css) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after further research and fumbling with css and jquery I finally solved it.

My lack of understanding of css is at fault here.

**Bottom line:** I just had to override the default state of the DOM element via jquery in order to keep the menu from hiding again once clicked.

You can check the result [here](http://www.mattlebrun.com/hacks/b-circ-menu/).

Thanks for the suggestions though. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you could have handlers for both the mousedown and mouseup events, and a timing mechanism that is accessible to both.

On mousedown you start the timing mechanism and start the slow animation.

In the mouseup you either

- complete the animation if the time lag since the mousedown is below a certain threshold (I.e. it was a fast click)
- end the animation and return the menu to the unopened state if the time lag since the mousedown is above the threshold ( I.e. it was a click + hold)

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the `:target` selector.

http://css-tricks.com/on-target/